# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0...' - After installing .NET Core 7 'dotnet watch run' not working

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-cli, .net-7.0

After the .Net 7.0 update, when I use `dotnet watch run` I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified. File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly,
> String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
> ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive,
> ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
> System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
> at System.StartupHookProvider.CallStartupHook(StartupHookNameOrPath
> startupHook)    at System.StartupHookProvider.ProcessStartupHooks()

I can successfully build and run the project using Visual Studio, but can't use **dotnet cli**. How can this error be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried adding [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) which will fix the SDK to previous version?

Comment: I recommend changing the title of your question to be more searchable for others. Your current title is too generic, i.e., people can get this error in many other situations. I'd use something like "Upgrading .netcore 6 to 7 stopped `dotnet watch run` working."

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to the Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version), the SDK uses the latest installed version and this is an expected behavior:

> The .NET CLI must choose an SDK version for every dotnet command. It
> uses the latest SDK installed on the machine by default,
> even if the project targets an earlier version of the .NET runtime.

So, it is not a real solution but changing the target framework of the project solves the issue.

[image]

---

Changing .Net version of the project is not a simple process so as a workaround, you can add a dummy word to the end of CLI command and it works:

```
dotnet watch run xyz
```

---

Another workaround, **global.json** below may help: [select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version)

> On rare occasions, you may need to use an earlier version of the SDK.
> You specify that version in a global.json file. The "use latest"
> policy means you only use global.json to specify a .NET SDK version
> earlier than the latest installed version.

**Create** a global.json file and point it to the v6 SDK. global.json can be placed **anywhere** in the project file hierarchy.

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "6.0.403"
    }
}
```

---

You can find out current and installed SDK's by running:

```
dotnet --info
```

Comment: You can also add run with word, ie dotnet watch run bogus

Comment: Why does the bogus word work? "dotnet watch run bogus" What does that change?

Comment: Liked that workaround `dotnet watch run xyz` the most!

Comment: And your first option, i.e., upgrading the target framework to `dotnet7` is not really the answer to your question. I'd remove that part.

Comment: why does adding a dummy word do anything?

Comment: I used the global.json solution and now get another error. `No instances of MSBuild could be detected.`

Comment: What IDE is on screenshot? In visual studio latest available target framework is 4.8

Comment: In VS Code > Right click on the solution in solution explorer > click properties - to get this above window in the screenshot.

Answer (score 13):

Giving all more context here. After the `dotnet` update to 7.0 version, I started getting the runtime issue using `cli` commands. Specifically `dotnet watch` inside a project from a .sln solution.

This behavior is expected, as per the [.NET SDK DOC here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version). Ideally, I believe a `global.json` file, pointing to expected SDK version, should be created from the beginning, but it's not.

If you go over Tools > Preferences > SDK Locations >  .NET Core (on VS) you will be able to see all the available versions ordered by the latest version. All we have to do here to fix this is create a `global.json`file inside the project providing the same `.net` version defined in the project properties. This file looks like below:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "X.X.X"
  }
}
```

Observe that X.X.X should be replaced by the .NET version of the project.

In the end, the problem is caused by the hierarchy of .NET version search by the `cli`, it will always look for the latest except in the case you define this `global.json` file.

Comment: dotnet watch using the latest SDK is expected, but the way the article is written I would expect the app to run in most cases. However, the error is that it can't find the System.Runtime. This error would not allow it to work under any circumstances.

Comment: @Justin  absolutely, as from there "... On rare occasions, you may need to use an earlier version of the SDK. You specify that version in a global.json file. ..." suppose to be the exception, but it's not. In the scenario here is the rule to make things work.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the solution was to add a global.json to the root of your project. With the SDK version, you want to use.

{
"sdk": {
"version": "6.0.403"
}
}

For me 6.0.403 that forces dotnet watch to use this version.

Comment: It's flexible than changing framework of the project, which will affect all nuget packages' working