# Installing .net-core 7 stops `dotnet watch run` working on .net-core 6 projects

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project that is using `net6` as the target framework. I recently installed .net core 7 SDK on my PC. After that, when I use `dotnet watch run` I get a strange error:

```
Unhandled exception. 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
The system cannot find the file specified.
.....
```

As the error suggests it is looking for .net 7 dlls in my project, while my project is targeting .net 6!

For a quick hack, I added a `global.json` in the root of project to explicitly using .net 6 SDK to build my project. However, I want a proper solution, and to know the reason behind this error.

Please note that I only experience this issue with `dotnet watch run`. I.e., other cases like `dotnet build`, `dotnet run`, `dotnet publish` are all fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367760/unhandled-exception-system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-ass), that imho also has the wrong answer marked as true.

The correct answer should be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74396378/287560), that links to the [original documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version).

This is the expected behavior and a breaking change, because the .NET cli will always look for the latest version except in the case you define this in a global.json file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that thread, though I'd choose a better title to make it more searchable. But I still can't get my head around why they did such a design that `dotnet watch run` doesn't work but `dotnet run` does! The funny thing is that sentence in their documentation says "On rare occasions, you may need to use an earlier version of the SDK.....". Using `dotnet watch run` is not a rare case!!

Comment: By the way, I liked that trick mentioned in the accepted answer `dotnet watch run xyz` the most!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into your `web.config` file or other configs that are in use. You are specifically looking for `<assemblies>` tags, so you will need to search for all occurrences of `<assemblies` in your repo. Look at all matches and see what their version is, the problematic assembly in your case is `System.Runtime`, but it's possible that you have other similar problems.

Comment: Thanks. I have neither `web.config` nor any use of the term `assemblies` in my repo.

Comment: @Mojtaba somehow your assemblies are specified. Do you have an AppFile.config?

Comment: No. Usually there is no `web.config` or `appfile.config` in net core apps. BTW, if your theory is right, why the error does not occur for other commands, e.g., `dotnet build` or `dotnet run`