# Assembly missing even if I have clearly specified as a csc reference

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the `csc` compiler works. I created a basic program as follows:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

I then copied some key elements from the `csc` command that results when you do a `dotnet build`:

```
dotnet exec "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.5\ref\net7.0\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.5\ref\net7.0\System.Console.dll" .\test.cs
```

The process runs successfuly and I get an executable at the end. However, when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why does this occur when I have clearly specified the referenced the assembly `System.Runtime`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367760/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-7-0-0-0-after-ins

Comment: @HansPassant how does that have anything to do with the OP?