# Why do I get a FileNotFoundException in production environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, runtime-error, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7.0 project that works fine in development environment. However, when I publish it and run it in the production environment, I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` error pointing to this file:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried various solutions, including ensuring the project is correctly published and installing the appropriate ASP.NET Core SDK version in the production environment. However, the issue persists.

Additionally, my source code worked fine on the same server in previous publishes, and this problem occurred after some code changes.
Program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                       .CreateLogger();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Host.UseSerilog().ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    });

    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AfgAzadUnConnection");

    builder.Services.Configure(connectionString);

    var app = builder.Build();

    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
         app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseRequestLocalization("en");
    app.UseSetVisitorId();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapHub<OnlineVisitorHub>("/chathub");

    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "اجرای اپلیکشن با خطا  مواجه شد.");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Configure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I26rq.png)

Has anyone encountered this error before? What are some possible solutions to resolve this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add your code please!!

Comment: Run the following command in your production environment `dotnet --list-runtimes` make sure that you have `7.0.0` runtime installed

Comment: See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367760/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-7-0-0-0-after-ins)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

In the production server environment, both .NET 6 and .NET 7 versions are installed, as confirmed by the `dotnet --list-runtimes`  command. However

Comment: Wich OS are you using in production environment? What are the settings for the build process? Did they match the production environment? Check if the value used for Target Runtime match the target environment.

Comment: I use Windows 11 on my local machine and Windows Server 2022 on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a peculiar issue in my ASP.NET Core project, and I wanted to share the solution that resolved it. I had the following code in my **ApplicationName.csproj** file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<Optimize>True</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controller\**" />
    <Compile Remove="Model\**" />
    <Content Remove="Controller\**" />
    <Content Remove="Model\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controller\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Model\**" />
    <None Remove="Controller\**" />
    <None Remove="Model\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Strangely, removing this code resolved the System.IO.FileNotFoundException issue that I was facing. If anyone has insights into why these specific configurations were causing the problem, I would appreciate further clarification.

It's worth noting that the project worked fine with these configurations in previous publishes, and the issue arose after making some code changes. If anyone has encountered a similar situation or has additional recommendations, I would be grateful for your insights.

Thanks!